# matplotlib: How to pick up shift click on figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent, shift, modifier-key

I have a matplotlib and I have created a `button_press_event` like this:

```
self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onClick)

def onClick(self, event)
    if event.button == 1:
        # draw some artists on left click

    elif event.button == 2:
        # draw a vertical line on the mouse x location on wheel click

    elif event.button == 3:
        # clear artists on right click
```

Now is it possible to modify the wheel click handler to something like this

```
    elif event.button == 2 or (event.button == 1 and event.key == "shift"):
        # draw a vertical line on the mouse x location 
        # on wheel click or on shift+left click 
        # (alternative way if there is no wheel for example)
```

It seems that `button_press_event` doesn't support keys and `key_press_event` doesn't support mouse button clicks, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also bind a key press and key release events and do something like:

```
self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', self.on_key_release)

...

def on_key_press(self, event):
   if event.key == 'shift':
       self.shift_is_held = True

def on_key_release(self, event):
   if event.key == 'shift':
       self.shift_is_held = False
```

Then you can check in your `onClick` function if `self.shift_is_held`.

```
if event.button == 3:
    if self.shift_is_held:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea and workaround until a proper support for modifier keys with mouse buttons is implemented. Thanks Viktor!

Comment: FYI, you could use `event.key == 'shift+left'` to capture `shift` + `left` keyboard buttons

Comment: I like this answer, but I think it has issues when multiple keys are pressed, since `key_release_event` doesn't say _which_ key is released. E.g., consider:
1. press shift (`key_press_event`, `key='shift'`)
2. press ctrl (`key_press_event`, `key='ctrl+shift'`)
3. release shift (`key_release_event`, `key='ctrl+shift'`)
4. release ctrl (`key_release_event`, `key='ctrl'`)
At the end, no keys are held but `shift_is_held==True`. You might change the conditionals to `if 'shift' in event.key`, but then if you release ctrl first shift is still held and yet `shift_is_held==False`... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Qt then you can simply use:

```
def onClick(self, event)
    # queries the pressed modifier keys
    mods = QGuiApplication.queryKeyboardModifiers()
    if event.button == 1 and mods == Qt.ShiftModifier:
        # do something when shift-clicking
```